# Add multiple keys with multiple values in Redis

Tags: redis, insert, nosql, newline

I have the following txt file

```
hset '0' firstName 'Abel' lastName 'Spencer' birthday '29992291634' gender 'male' task 'farmer' zipcode '1845AP'
 hset '1' firstName 'Erick' lastName 'Leonard' birthday '29632181211' gender 'female' task 'engineer' zipcode '1382FS'
 hset '2' firstName 'Janice' lastName 'Montes' birthday '2932445433' gender 'male' task 'researcher' zipcode '2634IE'
 hset '3' firstName 'Gretchen' lastName 'Proctor' birthday '294531491649' gender 'male' task 'researcher' zipcode '2375XQ'
 hset '4' firstName 'Lawanda' lastName 'Velazquez' birthday '2930282182' gender 'female' task 'industrial designer' zipcode '0684PY'
 hset '5' firstName 'Robbie' lastName 'Wilkins' birthday '29661912226' gender 'male' task 'miner' zipcode '0362PI'
 hset '6' firstName 'Carla' lastName 'Randall' birthday '293521621717' gender 'male' task 'farmer' zipcode '2746NM'
 hset '7' firstName 'Heath' lastName 'Dickson' birthday '29644123257' gender 'male' task 'industrial designer' zipcode '2367TG'
 hset '8' firstName 'Kendra' lastName 'Rodgers' birthday '2968479340' gender 'male' task 'engineer' zipcode '2626NM'
 hset '9' firstName 'Brandie' lastName 'Finley' birthday '294831481958' gender 'male' task 'miner' zipcode '1135SF'
 hset '10' firstName 'Rose' lastName 'Escobar' birthday '29752122345' gender 'male' task 'engineer' zipcode '0362PI'
 hset '11' firstName 'Ernest' lastName 'Robinson' birthday '2997161945' gender 'male' task 'researcher' zipcode '2501PZ'
 hset '12' firstName 'Randal' lastName 'Larsen' birthday '294531491649' gender 'female' task 'tailor' zipcode '2626NM'
 hset '13' firstName 'Ismael' lastName 'Dickerson' birthday '2930282182' gender 'female' task 'farmer' zipcode '1135SF'
 hset '14' firstName 'Keri' lastName 'Brennan' birthday '298031187' gender 'male' task 'doctor' zipcode '2746NM'
 hset '16' firstName 'Roberta' lastName 'Morse' birthday '294531501649' gender 'female' task 'miner' zipcode '1704PS'
 hset '17' firstName 'Colby' lastName 'Boone' birthday '2943344132' gender 'female' task 'water worker' zipcode '2266LW'
 hset '18' firstName 'Cornelius' lastName 'Herring' birthday '298231221743' gender 'female' task 'researcher' zipcode '2375XQ'
 hset '19' firstName 'Teddy' lastName 'Martin' birthday '295141671752' gender 'male' task 'water worker' zipcode '2626NM'
```

These are only the first 20 rows but there are a total of 510 rows. I want to add each row to redis, but I don't want to put them in manually. I tried copy-pasting the entire thing but I get the following error repeated over and over again:
`(error) ERR unknown command 'gender', with args beginning with: 'male' 'task' 'engineer' 'zipcode' '2626NM'  (error) ERR unknown command 'gender', with args beginning with: 'male' 'task' 'engineer' 'zipcode' '2626NM'` etc, etc.
Is there a way to add all keys with their respective values instantly without having to go through each one manually?

I tried copy-pasting the entire txt file, I expected all the keys to be set without any problems, but I just got a repeating error

Answer (score 1):

`redis-cli` can handle this.  For example imagine I have a file named `rediscommands.txt` containing:

```
hset myhash a 1 b 2 c 3
hset myotherhash a 2 b 3 c 99
```

I can then run all of the commands in it by invoking `redis-cli` like so:

```
$ redis-cli < rediscommands.txt
(integer) 3
(integer) 3
```

The responses for each Redis command in the file are output to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis-cli to do this from the command line:

```bash
redis-cli < my-file-full-of-redis-commands.txt
```